# az aks browse doesn't open browser automatically on WSL and only showing JSON instead of the dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, azure, azure-kubernetes-service

`az aks browse` works fine on my Mac Mini, but I'm trying to work with it in WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 with Azure CLI on a Windows 10 machine.

```
$ az version                      
This command is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
{
  "azure-cli": "2.1.0",
  "azure-cli-command-modules-nspkg": "2.0.3",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.1.0",
  "azure-cli-nspkg": "3.0.4",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.4",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

Kubernetes 1.14.8 which shouldn't make a difference given it works fine in macOS. Appears to be an issue with WSL2.

The first issue is running:

`az aks browse -g <groupname> -n <clustername>`

Just brings up the following in `az cli`:

```
Proxy running on http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Press CTRL+C to close the tunnel..
```

It doesn't automatically open the browser from WSL2 like it does in macOS and Linux. So you have to `CTRL + Click` the `http://127.0.0.1:8001` which will open the browser.

The second issue is it only brings up a JSON response with a list of API endpoints that looks like the following:

```
paths   
0   "/api"
1   "/api/v1"
2   "/apis"
3   "/apis/"
4   "/apis/acme.cert-manager.io"
5   "/apis/acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2"
6   "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io"
7   "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"
8   "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io"
9   "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
10  "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io"
11  "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1"
12  "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"
13  "/apis/apps"
14  "/apis/apps/v1"
....
```

And doesn't do anything after that.

Followed all of the necessary steps for `az login`, `az aks get-credentials`, and `RBAC`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect it to work like `az login` and open up a new tab in default browser. But somehow it doesn't work like that. I think the fix must come from azure CLI.

Temporarily, For `az aks browse` you can setup an environment variable on WSL.

```
export BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

In this case next when I run `az aks browse` it will open up the dashboard in new chrome tab.

You can use this variable to use your favorite browser. I would also add this variable to `.bashrc` or profile to be added on every session.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of two things. You need the `BROWSER` variable and there is a bug (as of Sep-2020) where `az-cli` doesn't detect interactive session correctly (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/issues/55)

So you need to modify `~/.bashrc`:

```
export BROWSER="/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
```

end then you can run your browser spawning commands with prefix `DISPLAY=:0` (sets that environment variable for duration of command; in this case az uses it to determine if the session is interactive and a browser should/could be spawned). So for you:

```
DISPLAY=:0 az aks browse -g <groupname> -n <clustername>
```